# mutate, case_when and str_detect: Trigger more than the first positive case

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, tibble

I have a dataframe df for which I'd like to create a new column filled with certain strings depending on which keywords/strings are found in the 'title' column.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tibble(
  id = c(36933814, 36921141, 39601489, 36898335, 36432859, 33447951),
  treatment_modalities = c("HIFU", "UAE", "UAE; RFA; HIFU", "UAE; RFA", "UAE; HIFU", "UAE"),
  no_patients = c(32, NA, 152, NA, 15, 428),
  year = c(2023, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023),
  title = c(
    "Title with keyword1 and keyword2 inside of it.",
    "A second title with kword3 and keyword1 inside of it.",
    "Here we have kword4 and nothing else to see.",
    "A title with kword4 and kword3 inside of it.",
    "And one with keyword1, keyword2 and kword3 in it.",
    "This title does not contain a keyword."
  ),
)
```

I can detect and write the first found keyword/string but then of course case_when stops and potential additional detections are not triggered:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(title_keyword = case_when(
    str_detect(df$title, regex("keyword1", ignore_case = T)) ~ "k1",
    str_detect(df$title, regex("keyword2", ignore_case = T)) ~ "k2",
    str_detect(df$title, regex("kword3", ignore_case = T)) ~ "k3",
    str_detect(df$title, regex("kword4", ignore_case = T)) ~ "k4",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_), .after = year)
```

Is case_when the wrong helper function for this? Maybe somehow with if_else and paste additionally to mutate?

Expected output would be:

```
tibble::tibble(
  id = c(36933814, 36921141, 39601489, 36898335, 36432859, 33447951),
  treatment_modalities = c("HIFU", "UAE", "UAE; RFA; HIFU", "UAE; RFA", "UAE; HIFU", "UAE"),
  no_patients = c(32, NA, 152, NA, 15, 428),
  year = c(2023, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023),
  title_keyword = c("k1; k2", "k3; k1", "k4", "k4; k3", "k1; k2; k3", NA),
  title = c(
    "Title with keyword1 and keyword2 inside of it.", "A second title with kword3 and keyword1 inside of it.",
    "Here we have kword4 and nothing else to see.", "A title with kword3 and kword4 inside of it.",
    "And one with keyword1, keyword2 and kword3 in it.", "This title does not contain a keyword."
  ),
)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a bit more parsimoniously using the `stringr` package's `str_extract_all` to first extract all the keywords and then `str_replace_all` to replace them:

```
ll <- lapply(str_extract_all(df$title, regex("keyword1+|keyword2+|kword3+|kword4+", ignore_case = TRUE)),
             paste, collapse = "; ")
df$title_keyword <- unlist(lapply(ll, str_replace_all, regex(c("keyword1" = "k1",
                                                     "keyword2" = "k2",
                                                     "kword3" = "k3",
                                                     "kword4" = "k4"),
                                                   ignore_case = TRUE)))
```

The `+` in the regex looks for one or more instances of the pattern.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 6
        id treatment_modalities no_patients  year title                                                 title_keyword
     <dbl> <chr>                      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                                 <chr>        
1 36933814 HIFU                          32  2023 Title with keyword1 and keyword2 inside of it.        "k1; k2"     
2 36921141 UAE                           NA  2022 A second title with kword3 and keyword1 inside of it. "k3; k1"     
3 39601489 UAE; RFA; HIFU               152  2023 Here we have kword4 and nothing else to see.          "k4"         
4 36898335 UAE; RFA                      NA  2023 A title with kword4 and kword3 inside of it.          "k4; k3"     
5 36432859 UAE; HIFU                     15  2023 And one with keyword1, keyword2 and kword3 in it.     "k1; k2; k3" 
6 33447951 UAE                          428  2023 This title does not contain a keyword.                ""
```

Comment: Nice to see an answer that scales up well!

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas! I edited to add (accidentally left off `ignore_case`). I kept the `+` in there and the explanation, but it may not need it (I'm not a regex expert though)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the `+` is super needed (I actually think it would only fire if you had two identical keywords concatenated, `"Title with keyword1keyword1"`), but I'm not 100% sure of that...

Answer (score 0):

You can separate columns that flag the keyword and then combined them:

```
     df %>% 
       mutate(
         k1 = case_when(str_detect(title, regex("keyword1", ignore_case = T)) ~ "k1", TRUE ~ NA_character_),
         k2 = case_when(str_detect(title, regex("keyword2", ignore_case = T)) ~ "k2", TRUE ~ NA_character_),
         k3 = case_when(str_detect(title, regex("kword3", ignore_case = T)) ~   "k3", TRUE ~ NA_character_),
         k4 = case_when(str_detect(title, regex("kword4", ignore_case = T)) ~   "k4", TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
       rowwise() %>%
       mutate(
         title_keyword=paste(c(na.omit(k1), na.omit(k2), na.omit(k3), na.omit(k4)), collapse = ";"),
         title_keyword = ifelse(title_keyword=="", NA, title_keyword)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
paste2 <- function(x,...){
  newx <- x[nzchar(x)]
  out <- paste(newx,...)
  if_else(nzchar(out)==0,NA_character_,out)
}

df2 <- df%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(key1=ifelse(str_detect(title, regex("keyword1", ignore_case = T)),"k1",""),
         key2=ifelse(str_detect(title, regex("keyword2", ignore_case = T)),"k2",""),
         key3=ifelse(str_detect(title, regex("kword3", ignore_case = T)),"k3",""),
         key4=ifelse(str_detect(title, regex("kword4", ignore_case = T)),"k4",""),
         new=paste2(c(key1,key2,key3,key4),sep=";",collapse=";")) %>%
  select(-starts_with("key")) %>%
  ungroup()
df2

# A tibble: 6 x 6
        id treatment_modalities no_patients  year title                                                 new     
     <dbl> <chr>                      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                                 <chr>   
1 36933814 HIFU                          32  2023 Title with keyword1 and keyword2 inside of it.        k1;k2   
2 36921141 UAE                           NA  2022 A second title with kword3 and keyword1 inside of it. k1;k3   
3 39601489 UAE; RFA; HIFU               152  2023 Here we have kword4 and nothing else to see.          k4      
4 36898335 UAE; RFA                      NA  2023 A title with kword4 and kword3 inside of it.          k3;k4   
5 36432859 UAE; HIFU                     15  2023 And one with keyword1, keyword2 and kword3 in it.     k1;k2;k3
6 33447951 UAE                          428  2023 This title does not contain a keyword.                NA
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Per the comments, here is a different generalized approach that avoids writing out so many conditions:

```
key <- c("keyword1", "keyword2", "kword3", "kword4")
value <- c("k1", "k2", "k3", "k4")

df |>
  mutate(title_keyword = map_chr(title, ~ str_flatten(value[str_detect(.x, key)], ";")),
         title_keyword = na_if(title_keyword, ""))
```

**How it works**

1. First create a vector for key-value pairs. `key` is what you would like to match, `value` is what you would like to return element-wise if `key` is matched.
2. Iterate over `title` and for each title we test for all the keywords using `str_detect`. This will return a vector of logical values, which we use to access the values.
3. Using `str_flatten` we collapse the returned values into a character string (`"k1;k2"`).
4. `str_flatten` will return `""` for no match, so we use `na_if` to convert it to `NA`.

**Output**

```
        id treatment_modalities no_patients  year title                  title~1
     <dbl> <chr>                      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>  
1 36933814 HIFU                          32  2023 Title with keyword1 a~ k1;k2  
2 36921141 UAE                           NA  2022 A second title with k~ k1;k3  
3 39601489 UAE; RFA; HIFU               152  2023 Here we have kword4 a~ k4     
4 36898335 UAE; RFA                      NA  2023 A title with kword4 a~ k3;k4  
5 36432859 UAE; HIFU                     15  2023 And one with keyword1~ k1;k2;~
6 33447951 UAE                          428  2023 This title does not c~ NA
```

---

**Old**

Rather than conditionally set the value of `title_keyword`, why not just extract the values you are looking for:

```
df |> 
  mutate(title_keyword = map_chr(str_match_all(title, "(k)e?y?word(\\d)"), ~ str_c(str_c(.x[,2], .x[,3]), collapse = ";")),
         title_keyword = na_if(title_keyword, ""))
```

1. Here we match your `kword` and `keyword` and extract the `k` and the digit at the end (`\\d`).
2. We paste these captures together and then collapse them all delimited by `;`.

Comment: It seems likely that OP is using `keyword` and `kword` as placeholders for this example and they are not the actual keywords they are interested in finding. A nice answer would generalize to cases where the desired values aren't necessarily clean substrings of the matched patterns.

Comment: Right, it would be good to know if the the output value is somehow related to the keywords they are trying to match. If that were the case then you could still extract it more methodically than writing out so many `str_detect` statements.

Comment: jpsmith has a nice solution with only 2 `str_` function that scales up.

Comment: Agreed! Trying to offer a solution that minimizes the need for changes if more keywords are added.